# Статичное дерево HTML + CSS

Tags: jquery, html, javascript, css

Добрый день!

Подскажите, как можно сделать пунктир к дочернему элементу?

Как тут /

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Вот вариант на чистом CSS (jsfiddle).](http://jsfiddle.net/8CR2z/) Картинки там не нужны.

```
span { /* обертка пункта */
     text-decoration: none;
     display: block; /* растянем до правого края блока */
     margin: 0 0 0 1.2em;     
     background-color: transparent;
     border: dotted silver; /* цвет линий */
     border-width: 0 0 1px 1px; /* границы: низ и лево */
   }
   span a {/* текст элемента дерева */
      display: block;
      position: relative;
      top: .95em; /* смещаем узел на середину линии */
      background-color: #fff; /* закраска в цвет фона обязательна иначе будет видно линию */
      margin: 0 0 .2em .7em; /* делаем промежуток между узлами, отодвигаем левее  */
      padding: 0 0.3em; /* небольшой отступ от линии */
   }
```

Идея в том, что мы делаем границы, а сам текст смещаем вверх, таким образом получаем эффект линии ведущей к узлу.

Comment: добавьте на первый уровень в конец еще пару узлов. если захочется добавить плюсики для раскрытия тоже будет сложно.

Comment: дело вкуса, я спорить не буду. если бы позволяли сроки, то мне больше удовольствия принесло реализовать все на css. но это мое субьективное мнение...

Comment: это копипаста с хабры вашего поста? иначе как-то странно слышать про вкусы и сроки...

Comment: нет, реализация не моя, а найдена где-то на просторах интернета, возможно и с хабра... но понравилась мне больше всего.

Comment: в таком случае не помешают ссылки на полное решение:

 * [Статичное дерево html+css](http://habrahabr.ru/post/55753/)
 * [Интерактивное дерево html+css+jquery](http://habrahabr.ru/post/56278/)
 * [С запоминанием состояния html+css+jquery+cookies](http://habrahabr.ru/post/59823/)

[Пример](http://r3code.ru/projects/multi-derevo/multi-derevo-jquery-v5-utf8-cookie.html)

Answer (score 4):

Картинкой. Смотрите [здесь](http://jquery.bassistance.de/treeview/demo/). Для соответствующих `<li>` устанавливается свой класс, и в css для класса указывается `background`. firebug в руки и смотреть что и как...

Comment: Вот, например, и у Microsoft на MSDN сделано [как][1]  
Одна общая картинка для всех пиктограмм менюшек, а затем уже к каждому пункту приставляется свой блок, который вырезает нужный кусок пиктограммки 13х9 из общего для всех изображения     
.cl_nav_dots{top:-3px;left:-1511px;}


  [1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd831853